# Apache Flink + Openstack Swift

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, openstack-swift, flink-state

I came across this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-swift-fs-hadoop repo.

Does Apache Flink still support this OS Swift plugin File System or not?

It's not listed on the current site but has been on the previous versions(1.10).

Would be great if someone can give me a guide as to what the best approach would be to have configured savepoints being stored in OS Swift.